# How to compute $\iint_S \mathrm{curl} F\cdot n dS$ where $S$ is the below portion of $z=x^2+y^2$

Tags: integration, curl

How to compute $\iint_S \mathrm{curl}  F\cdot n dS$ where $S$ is the portion of $z=x^2+y^2$ below  $z=16$, $n$ is the normal vector pointing down, and $F=(z,x,y^2)$?

I thought of the stokes theorem, but I'm not sure what to compute. So I was trying directly computing $$\mathrm{curl} \ F=(2y,1,1)$$ but what is a normal vector I can use? the surface parametrization could be difficult.

Comment: Stokes' theorem converts the the integral with the curl on the surface to an integral without the curl on the boundary on the surface.  So what is the boundary, what is the line integral you get around the boundary, and what does it evaluate to?  Hint: it's a circle, and parameterizing circles is easy.

Comment: @Aaron But I think it's a paraboloid, then I get troubles trying to parametrize it. For a circle I can use polar coordinates.

Comment: The surface is a parabolid, but if you apply Stokes' theorem, it will convert your integral to an integral on the boundary, and the boundary is a circle.  You then no longer need to worry about parameterizing the paraboloid.

Comment: @Aaron What is the normal vector in this case? $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4 (2*2\sin t,1,1).(a,b,c) r dtd\theta $$

Comment: The boundary is a CIRCLE, which is ONE DIMENSIONAL.  You will not have a double integral.

Comment: You keep ignoring the point of Stokes’s Theorem and are trying to evaluate the surface integral directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute $\iint_S curl \hspace{1mm}\mathbf{F}\cdot{\mathbf{N}}dS$, you can use Stokes' theorem, noting that a parametrisation of the boundary, C, is: $\mathbf{r}(t) = \ (4\cos{t}, 4\sin{t}, 16) $:

$$\iint_S curl \hspace{1mm}\mathbf{F}\cdot{\mathbf{N}}dS = \int_C \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))\cdot{d\mathbf{r}}\\ = \int_C (16, 4\cos{t}, 16\sin^2{t}) \cdot{(-4\sin{t}, 4\cos{t},0)}\hspace{1mm}dt\\ = \int_0^{2\pi}-64\sin{t}\hspace{0.5mm} +16\cos^2{t}\hspace{1mm}dt = 16\pi.  $$

Hope this helps.